# scroll a webpage when the scrollbar is hidden - selenium

Tags: java, selenium

My webpage's scrollbar is hidden but appears when I move my cursor and gets hidden again.

What I need is to scroll down the webpage to hover over an element and then click on a button (button appears when hover over the element).

I tried using javascript, actions() but those didn't make me happy.

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,100);");

Comment: can you paste your code here ? Also you can try to press page down button if you want

Comment: public void scrollIntoElement() {
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(100,0);");
    }

And I cannot try pressing the page down button as I don't have any element to send keys, I mean no any text field elements.

Comment: Alright, so you cant use action class because it required element for a moment.

Comment: if possible please provide your site will quickly check

Comment: @Rock I tried the following as well.

'public void scrollIntoElement(WebElement element) throws InterruptedException {

 ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);", element);
    }'

Answer (score 0):

To scroll down please refer below code:

```
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

 // This  will scroll down the page by  1000 pixel vertical     
     js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)");
```

Comment: give your site if possible

Answer (score 0):

when you know which element you are looking for, you can scroll down directly to the **element** like this:

suppose your element is as below:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id_of_element"));
```

now you can scroll to `element` :

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Comment: I tried this, but this isn't working, neither error messages nor scroll.

Comment: is it possible for you to mention the website?

Comment: I found another solution here. You can try it: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/9660/40543